# What is difference between npm i @angular/material and ng add @angular/material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried `npm i @angular/material` and it installed `@angular/material` package into my angular CLI project.

Then I tried `ng add @angular/material` and I got prompt to choose between different themes, I was expecting some changes in `style.scss` but no changes introduced.

What is difference between the output of two commands?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm i @angular/material` only installs the `@angular/material` package.

On the other hand, `ng add @angular/material` -

1. installs the `@angular/material` package
2. installs the `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/animations` packages
3. sets a theme for your application
4. sets up a global Angular Material typography styles (optional)
5. sets up browser animations for Angular Material (optional)

In your `styles.scss` file, following lines will be added -

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

In the `angular.json` file, you'll find a reference to your selected theme -

```json
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```

If you allow set up the Material typography, then a `class="mat-typography"` and links to the `Roboto` font and `Material Icon` will be added in your `index.html` file -

```html
<head>
    ...
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="mat-typography">
    <dx-root></dx-root>
</body>
```

If you allow set up browser animations, then you'll find `BrowserAnimationsModule` readily imported and added in the `imports:` array of your `app.module.ts` -

```js
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

// and
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
],
```

It is well documented here - [Install Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#install-angular-material)

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail.
I have created ng workspace and then genrated angular application and library within it. Then I ran npm i @angular/material and then tried ng add @angular/material, for some reason the style.scss file in my application is not affected.
While as you explained in plain angular application (where no workspace is created) style.scss is updated. Thanks!!

Comment: @Alwaysalearner Does this answer your question? Anyway, I added material with `ng add` in workspace with multiple libraries and app. I always found the `styles.scss` modified. So, try again.